# Dialogflow Giving Specific options as valid for intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

So I have scoured the internet and finding it very difficult to find a solution to my problem. The issue is, I have many intents and these intents are also filtered by contexts handled by the webhook. I am trying to find a way to have a list from the webhooks last call, whether it be in the context params or some other form from to use as a valid phrase to trigger the intent.

These responses can be one word so doing @sys.any isn't viable, @sys.any also doesn't assign a key to a matched synonym either which would be helpful to process through the webhook after the intent has been called. The other issue is that I still need other intents to still be called if the intent with the list isn't matched.

So in short, I'm trying to find a way that could dynamically assign values for an entity based on a webhooks response to a phrase. And if the user does not match one of those phrases then I don't want it to be processed by that intent.

At the moment I am looking into a Fallback intent with the context relevant but this still feels hacky and would still have to use @sys.any along with figuring out the phrase via backend. I also beleive it's viable to validate on dialogflow than to validate through the backend too.

Any help or direction will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do this is a case for **User Entities**.
With them you can redefine an existing entity to have session specific values.

Have a look at the documentation: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/userentities

Comment: I think that would be the answer to my problem. It's just that the entity needs to be recognised as updated ready for the next call so I hope it's streamlined. You also pointed to the V1 API and I'm after a V2 method. Would that be session entity?

Comment: I'm accepting based on that it works but does take extra time to make the api call before receiving a response.

Comment: Yes. in v2 it is projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes